# why would this jquery live enter an infinite loop, where an almost identical one does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a form where the values are updated based on changes in either a select, or changes in a text field.

I started with

```
jQuery('select[name=measure]','form').live('change',function(){
 alert('triggered');
});
```

I then added the keyup for when the user alters a text box

```
jQuery('select[name=measure],input[name=amount]','form').live('change keyup',function(){
  alert('triggered');
});
```

For some reason this enters an infinite loop when I select an option, and is triggered multiple times on keyup (though not infinitely).

When I change to

```
...live('keyup', function()...
```

changes to the text-box are only triggered once. 
I could split them into two seperate .live events and then create a separate function, but that doesn't seem to be efficient code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's attaching the `change` and `keyup` to `select[name=measure]` and `input[name=amount]`.

I doubt you want the input to have a change event and the select to have a keyup event.

I recommend you separate these two live events. You probably don't need the `form` selector either.

```
$('select[name=measure]').live('change', SomeFunction);

$('input[name=amount]').live('keyup', SomeFunction);

function SomeFunction() {
    // this isn't inefficient
}
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/K7586/

---

or you could use `delegate()`

```
$("form")
    .delegate("input[name=amount]", "keyup", SomeFunction)
    .delegate("select[name=measure]", "change", SomeFunction);

function SomeFunction() {
    // this isn't inefficient
}
```

Comment: thanks hunter. I was thinking that this was't the most efficient use of code. I'll use the delegate as I know delegate is supposed to be more efficient, and it definitely looks like nicer code. 
Cheers